# How to save value in $_SESSION in php and retrieve

Tags: php, database

I want to show the `usermail` once I login and the page after login should show "Welcome alex01@gmail.com"
my login page php code is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="documentation";
    $usermail=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    $query="SELECT * FROM users where
    user_mail='$usermail' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['documentation']='true';
        $_SESSION['user_mail']=$_POST['email'];
        header('location:index.php');
    }
    else{echo 'wrong username or password';}

}
?>
```

The code of my index.php (the page user see after login)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_mail']=$_POST['email'];
if(!$_SESSION['documentation'])
{
    header('location:login.php');
}
?>
```

I am trying to save the `usermail` by

```
$_SESSION['user_mail']=$_POST['email'];
```

and I am trying to retrieve the value in index.php by writing

```
$_SESSION['user_mail']=$_POST['email'];
```

but it is not showing the user name

Comment: you are assigning on both pages, just `echo $_SESSION['user_mail'];` in index.php page

Comment: You should retrieve it vice versia in index.php $usermail = $_SESSION['user_mail'];

Comment: You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attacks has no attempt is made to validate the user submitted data (in this case the user's email and password) and it's not even escaped. Prepared statements should be used when using user submitted data in any query.

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.php` page retrive like this;

```
 echo $_SESSION['user_mail'];
```

Answer (score 1):

retrieve session by `echo $_SESSION['user_mail'];`

Answer (score 1):

to display session data, just write

```
echo $_SESSION['user_mail'];
```

Also ensure to start session on page where session is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of $_SESSION['user_mail] in index page with $_POST['email]. The problem is that $_POST['email'] is not set on index page, its only set on the login page.

So on index.php page you simply have to either

`echo $_SESSION['user_mail'];`

or

`$var = $_SESSION['user_mail']; 
echo $var;`

Answer (score 0):

For save in session variable:-

```
$usermail = $_SESSION['user_mail'];
```

and for show in same page .

```
echo $usermail;
```

in other page :-

```
//first start session
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["username"];
//or 
session_start();
$loginname=$_SESSION["username"];
echo $loginname;
```

Please, make sure the session is started on the page where session is being used.